# MySQL: How to set a row or byte-size limit on a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I took a look on stackoverflow to find similar questions/answers, but the answers where unsatisfactory. That's why I formulated the question in a different manner.

What I want: **I want to set a max row (or byte-size) limit on a innodb table**.

What I did:

**PHASE 1**

So I created an id column with the type `int(1)`. 
Then I created an index on the `id` column. The index choice was `PRIMARY`.

See below:

[image]

At the size column in the I tried to assign 1. Then clicked the "Go" button. 
MySQL Server gave me the following error:

```
1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys
```

Question: what does this error message mean?

I kept the Size column empty, and clicked GO. 
After doing so I gave the id column the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. 
Then I inserted 256 rows. They where inserted, just as expected.

**PHASE 2**

Then I tried to insert another 50 rows. 
I expect them to fail because of the type of id, which is `int(1)`.
To my surprise all 50 rows where inserted.

I thought that `int(1)` has a limit of `256`. 
See this link to back-up my claim: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Question: **why is it possible to insert more then 256 rows even if the column is `int(1)`?**

**PHASE 3**

I truncated the table, then altered using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` MAX_ROWS = 256
```

The row statistics are:

[image]

Again, I expect to have the ability to insert only 256 rows. 
So, I expect an error message or something after the insertion of the 257th row. So I tried to insert 300 rows.

To my surprise all 300 rows where inserted.

Main question: **How to set a row or byte-size limit on a MySQL table?**

Comment: from [MYSQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) on MAX_ROWS: "This is not a hard limit, but rather a hint to the storage engine that the table must be able to store at least this many rows.". I guess you need to check it yourself before inserting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to answer my own question, because I found the solution myself.

The most simple way to set the max row limit is to define the `id` column as one of these types:

- `TINYINT`
- `MEDIUMINT`
- `BIGINT`

Warning: the type: `INT` + size doesn't set a max rows limit.